# Prove that the diophantine equation $(xz+1)(yz+1)=az^{k}+1$ has infinitely many solutions in positive integers.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Given two positive integers $a$ and $k>3$ : From experimental data, it appears the diophantine equation

$(xz+1)(yz+1)=az^{k}+1$

has infinitely many solutions in positive integers $x,y, z$.

To motivate the question, it can easily be shown that if $k <3$,  the given diophantine equation has no solutions in positive integers $x, y ,z$ with $z>a$.

Proof: $(xz+1)(yz+1)=az^{k}+1$ may be simplified to $xyz^{2}+(x+y)z=az^{k}$. If $k=1$, this reduces to  $xyz+x+y=a$. Its clear that $a>z$ therefore there are no positive integral solutions in $x$ and $y$ when $z>a$. if $k=2$, we have the reduced equation $xyz+x+y=az$. We have $z$ | $x+y$, $z \le(x+y) \le xy$.  Therefore  $LHS=xyz+x+y>z^{2}$. Because $RHS=az$, we must have $a>z$ thus there are no solutions in positive integers $x ,y$ when $z>a$.

I would like to prove that given two positive integers $a$ and $k>3 $, the diophantine equation $(xz+1)(yz+1)=az^{k}+1$ has  infinitely many positive integer solutions $x, y, z$. I do not know how to start the proof.

Comment: For $z=1$ the diophantine equation becomes
$$(x+1)(z+1)=a+1,$$
which boils down to factoring $a+1$. For $k>3$, are you also looking only for solutions with $z>a^2+2a$?

Comment: For the case $k=2$, note that $x+y\leq xy$ fails if $x=y=1$.

Comment: The case $x=1$, $y=1$ can be proved separately.  We may assume $x>1$, $y>1$.

Comment: I've got finiteness for $z^3.$   The bound is $2a^2 + 2a-1,$  some sort of additional work required to get it down to $a^2 + 2a.$  Take me a while to typeset, it is just inequalities.

Comment: @will jagy, a proof for the $2a^{2} +2a-1$ bound is good enough.

Comment: @will jagy, leave your answer at the more specific question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3842292/prove-that-the-diophantine-equation-xz1yz1-az3-1-has-no-solutions-in?noredirect=1#comment7926351_3842292

Comment: I see. I will put it there  and a CW copy here. Proper way to do it.

Comment: Anyone with enough reputation, please place a bounty on this question. My reputation is still low

Comment: David, it is time, long past time, to say exactly where you got this question and what it means to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113484/discussion-between-david-jones-and-will-jagy).

Comment: David, a chat room was opened for this. That happens when a string of comments alternates between two users and an attempt is made to add one more reply. You should be able to see the link to the chat room as your attempted comment of about 15 minutes ago  but this is it:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113484/discussion-between-david-jones-and-will-jagy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is based on the excellent work of Will Jagy. This solves all cases of $k>3.$

---

Let $p<k$ be an odd prime such that $p\not\mid k.$

Solve $kd\equiv -1\pmod{p}.$ Let $n=(kd+1)/p.$ Note that since $p<k,$ $n>d.$

Then for any integer $t,$ we can take $z=a^{d}t^p$ so that $$\begin{align}az^k+1&=a^{kd+1}t^{kp}+1\\&=\left(a^nt^k\right)^p+1\\
&=(a^nt^k+1)\left(1+a^nt^k\sum_{j=1}^{p-1} (-1)^j\left(a^nt^k\right)^{j-1}\right)
\end{align}$$

Where the last equation is because when $p$ is odd, $$
\begin{align}u^p+1&=(u+1)
\sum_{j=0}^{p-1} (-1)^ju^j
\\&=(u+1)\left(1+u\sum_{j=1}^{p-1}(-1)^ju^{j-1}\right)\end{align}$$

Now, since $n>d,$ we can set $$
\begin{align}x&=a^{n-d}t^{k-p}\\
y&=a^{n-d}t^{k-p}\sum_{j=1}^{p-1} (-1)^j\left(a^nt^k\right)^{j-1}
\end{align}$$

For $k\geq 4$ we can always find such a $p$ by taking a prime factor of $n-1$ or $n-2$ if $n$ is even or odd, respectively.

So this solves all cases $k>3.$

---

You don't need $p$ prime, just that $1<p<k$ is odd and $\gcd(p,k)=1.$

**k even**

So when $k$ is even, we can take $p=k-1.$ Then $d=p-1$ and $n=p.$

Then for any integer $t,$ $$\begin{align}z&=a^{k-2}t^{k-1}\\x&=at\\y&=at\sum_{j=1}^{k-2}(-1)^j\left(a^{k-1}t^k\right)^{j-1}.\end{align}$$

**k odd**

Likewise, if $k=2m+1$ is odd, then you can take $p=2m-1,$ $d=m-1$ and $n=m.$  Then for any integer $t$:

$$\begin{align}z&=a^{m-1}t^{2m-1}\\
x&=at^2\\
y&=at^2\sum_{j=1}^{2m-2}(-1)^j\left(a^mt^{2m+1}\right)^{j-1}
\end{align}$$

is a solution.

---

In particular, for $k>3$ there are infinitely many solutions $(x,y,z)$ with $a\mid x$ and $x\mid y$ and $x\mid z.$

Comment: Good. I found something that works, but $x,y,z$  are all going to be powers of $a.$ Nicer if you can work in $a^v t^u$  for each.

Comment: Thomas, please read this short transcript, it is the reason i was willing to continue work on this: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/113484

Answer (score 7):

Getting there. Here is $k=4.$   a family of solutions to
$$  a z^4 + 1 = (xz+1)(yz+1)  $$

is parametrized by integer $t$ with

$$  y=at $$

$$ x = a^4 t^5 - at  $$

$$ z = a^2 t^3  $$

Both sides of the equation are
$$ a^9 t^{12} + 1  $$

=======================================

For that matter, we can take care of all $k \neq 0 \pmod 3$  this way.

When $k > 3$  and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 3,$  we may take
$$  y = a^{\frac{2k-5}{3}} \; t^{k-3}  $$
$$ z = a^2 t^3  $$
followed by
$$ x = y \left( y^2 z^2 - 1 \right)  $$

When $k > 3$  and $k \equiv 2 \pmod 3,$  we may take
$$  y = a^{\frac{k+1}{3}} \; t^{k-3}  $$
$$ z = a t^3  $$
followed by
$$ x = y \left( y^2 z^2 - 1 \right)  $$

Comment: +1 Nice work. I came up with a complete answer based on your work here. Basically, you need an odd prime $p<k$ which does not divide $k.$