# Prove that the diophantine equation $(xz+1)(yz+1)=az^{3} +1$ has no solutions in positive integers $x, y, z$ with $z>a^{2} +2a$.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, recreational-mathematics

Let $a$ be a positive integer that is **not** a perfect cube. From experimental data, it appears all solutions to $(xz+1)(yz+1)=az^{3} +1$ in positive integers $x, y, z$ occur when $z \le a^{2} +2a$ i.e it appears there are no solutions in $x, y,z$ with $z> a^{2} +2a$. Can this observation be proved?

To motivate the question, we shall prove that on the contrary if $a$ is a perfect cube, there are infinitely many positive integer solutions in $x, y, z$.

Proof.
Let $a=m^{3} $ for some integer $m$. Using the identity $n^{3} +1 =(n+1)(n^{2}-n+1)$, we see that $az^{3} +1=(mz)^{3} +1= (mz+1)((mz)^{2}-mz+1) $.

A family of solutions is then given by $x=m$, $y=m^{2}z - m$  where $z$ takes on any positive integer.

How do I go about proving the striking observation: There are **no** positive integer solutions  $x, y, z$ with $z>a^{2} +2a$ when the integer $a$ is not a perfect cube? Is there any counterexample?

Comment: I don't know if that could help, maybe setting $a=m^3+b$ with $0<b<(m+1)^3-m^3$.

Comment: It is already much clearer.

Comment: Your earlier question is related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3840780/prove-that-the-diophantine-equation-xz1yz1-azk1-has-infinitely-many

Comment: $z = 10, x = 9, y = 1, a = 1$ is a positive integer solution to the equation. Alas, doesn't meet $a$ not perfect cube requirement! :-)

Comment: Perhaps it helps to note that your diophantine equation is equivalent to the system of diophantine equations
\begin{eqnarray*}
x+y&=&vz\\
xy&=&az-v,
\end{eqnarray*}
and that the condition $z>a^2+2a$ is equivalent to $z\geq(a+1)^2$.

Comment: David, typed in. It appears the final section does not use calculus. Oh, If you do a search with,  sorted by $x$ within each fixed $a$,  and with my $az = xy + t,$   you will see that the largest $x$ occur at the extremes, $t=1$  or $t=a-1.$ As $t$ gets close to $a^{2/3}$ the values of $x$ become modest.

Comment: @DavidJones: My comment was that $(9.10 + 1)(1.10 + 1) = 1.10^3 + 1 \implies (91)(11) = 1001$, except it doesn't meet your constraint for $a$ to not be a perfect cube (1 is a perfect cube). It meets the $z > a^2 + 2a$ condition. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A concise Proof based on an earlier proof:

The given equation $(xz+1)(yz+1)=az^3+1$ can be rewritten as $az^2-xyz-(x+y)=0$. We shall show that for any solution $(x,y,z)$, we have $z \le a^2+2a. \ $
Note that $z \ | \ x+y$, therefore $z \le x+y. \ $  Treating $x, y$ as constants, the only positive solution for $z \ $ is   \begin{equation} z = \frac{xy+\sqrt{x^2y^2+4a(x+y)}} {2a}
\end{equation} In order for $z$ to be rational, the discriminant must be a perfect square. Therefore $w^2 = x^2y^2+4a(x+y)$. We see that $w > xy$ and $w \equiv xy \ ( $mod$ \ 2)$. We can write $w = xy + 2t$, $t > 0$.
Substituting $w$ above,  $(xy+2t)^2 = x^2y^2+4a(x+y)$. Expanding and simplifying, $txy - ax - ay +t^2 = 0$. Multiplying through by $t$ and factoring, $(tx-a)(ty-a)=a^2 - t^3$. We must have $t \le a-1$ otherwise $RHS<0$ and $LHS \ge 0$. Because $a$ is not a perfect cube, $a^2 - t^3 \not = 0$. The remainder of the proof utilizes the result: If $ab = c \  $ where $a,b, c \not = 0$ are integers then $a+b \le c+1$ if $c>0$ and $a+b \le -(c+1)$ if $c < 0$.
We now consider two cases:

Case $1: \ $  $ a^2 - t^3 >0 \ ;$
Using the result above on the factored equation, we have $(tx-a)+(ty-a) \le a^2 - t^3+1 \le a^2$.
Hence, $z \le x+y \le (a^2+2a)/t \le a^2+2a \\$.

Case $2: \ $  $ a^2 - t^3 < 0 \ ;$
As in case $1$, we have $(tx-a)+(ty-a) \le t^3 - a^2-1 \ $,  $x+y \le t^2 - (a^2-2a+1)/t < t^2$.  Hence , $z \le x+y < t^2 \le (a-1)^2 < a^2 +2a$

Answer (score 3):

Similar to finishing

[Is it true that $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2}{xy-t}$ has only finitely many distinct positive integer values with $x$, $y$ positive integers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829228/is-it-true-that-fx-y-dfracx2y2xy-t-has-only-finitely-many-distinct-i/1480206#1480206)

where I had an acceptable bound but needed help from Gerry Myerson to improve to the sharp bound.

We have $$ (xz+1)(yz+1) = a z^3 + 1  $$

This becomes

$$ a z^3 - xyz^2 - (x+y)z=0$$
or
$$ a z^2 - xyz - (x+y) = 0 $$

We get
$$    z = \frac{ xy + \sqrt{ x^2 y^2 + 4a(x+y) } }{2a}   $$

Let me also record

$$\color{fuchsia}{ z(az-xy) = x+y }$$
which follows directly from $ a z^2 - xyz - (x+y) = 0 $
Note also the simple
$$\color{fuchsia}{ z \leq x+y }$$

It is necessary to have square discriminant to get a rational value for $z,$   take
$$  w^2 =  x^2 y^2 + 4a(x+y) $$
We have $$ w > xy  $$  and
$$  w \equiv xy \pmod 2. $$
Therefore we can define an integer $t,$   when it all works, with
$$ w = xy+2t $$

Now $$ z = \frac{xy+w}{2a} = \frac{xy+xy+2t}{2a} = \frac{2xy+2t}{2a} = \frac{xy+t}{a}  $$

$$ z =  \frac{xy+t}{a}  $$

There are always three flavors for any $a$
$$ t=a-1 \; , \; y = 1 \; , \; x = a^2 - 3a +1 \; , \; z = a-2 $$
$$ t=1 \; , \; y = 2a-1 \; , \; x = 2a +1 \; , \; z = 4a $$
$$ t=1 \; , \; y = a+1 \; , \; x = a^2 +a -1 \; , \; z = a^2+2a $$

From
$$ x^2 y^2 +4a(x+y) = (xy+2t)^2 $$
we get  $$ t xy - ax -ay + t^2 = 0,  $$
$$ t^2 xy - tax -tay + t^3 = 0,  $$

$$  \color{red}{(tx-a)(ty-a) = a^2 - t^3}  $$

IF $a > 1$  and $t = a + \delta$  with $\delta \geq 0,$  we find

$$ ((a+\delta)x-a)((a+\delta)y-a) = a^2 - (a+\delta)^3  < 0 $$
since $a>1.$
However, the left hand side is non-negative, which is a contradiction.

$$ \color{red}{ t \leq a-1} $$

I will fill in the (lengthy) details in a bit.

I always have $x \geq y \geq 1$

IF $$ \color{blue}{  a^{2/3} < t \leq a-1} $$
we get

$$  (tx-a) (a-ty) = t^3 -a^2 > 0 $$
so $a-ty >0,$  $ty - a < 0,$
$$ ty < a  $$
$$ y < \frac{a}{t} < a^{1/3} $$

$$ a - ty \geq 1  $$
$$ tx-a \leq t^3 - a^2 $$
$$ tx \leq t^3 - (a^2 - a)$$
$$  x \leq t^2 - \frac{a^2 - a}{t} $$

**DETAIL:** As $t$ increases, $t^2$ increases, while $\frac{1}{t}$ decreases. Then $\frac{-1}{t}$ increases. We have $a \geq 2$  so that $a^2 - a > 0,$ so that
$\frac{-(a^2-a)}{t}$ increases. Together, $t^2 - \frac{a^2 - a}{t}$ increases and takes its maximum value at $t=a-1,$ that being $ a^2 - 3a + 1.$
Thus
$$ \color{magenta}{x \leq a^2 - 3a + 1}$$
$$xy + t < a^{7/3} -3a^{4/3} + a + a^{1/3} -1   $$

$$ z < a^{4/3} -3a^{1/3} + 1 + a^{-2/3} -\frac{1}{a}   $$

$$ \color{red}{ z < a^{4/3} }  $$ when  $a^{2/3} < t \leq a-1$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

I always have $x \geq y \geq 1$

IF $$ \color{blue}{1 \leq t <  a^{2/3} }$$

$$  (tx-a) (ty-a) = a^2 - t^3 > 0$$
$$  (tx-a) \leq a^2 -t^3$$
$$  tx  \leq a^2 + a - t^3 < a^2 + a$$

$$  x  \leq \frac{a^2 + a}{t}  $$

Meanwhile
$$ t^2 xy - ta(x+y)= -t^3 < 0 $$
$$txy < ta(x+y) \leq 2ax  $$
$$  ty < 2a
$$ y < \frac{2a}{t}   $$

Together
$$ xy < \frac{2 a^3 + 2a^2}{t^2}   $$
$$ xy + t <  \frac{2 a^3 + 2a^2}{t^2} + a^{2/3} $$
$$  z <  \frac{2 a^2 + 2a}{t^2} + \frac{1}{a^{1/3}} $$

IF $t \geq 2$
then $z < \frac{a^2 + a}{2}$

IF  $t=1$ we  have $$  (x-a)(y-a) = a^2 - 1 > 0   $$

If $x>a$ then $y>a.$      Then $y-a \geq 1$ and $x-a \leq a^2 - 1$
When $t=1$ we have $x \leq a^2 + a - 1.$
In general, when we have real $p \geq 1, q \geq 1,$ and $pq=c,$

the maximum of $p+q$ occurs when $p=1$ and $q=c$
so that $p+q \leq 1+c$

With  $  (x-a)(y-a) = a^2 - 1    $ we get $x-a+y-a \leq a^2.$ Thus
$$   x+y \leq a^2 + 2a$$

With $t=1,$ we know $z = x+y.$  With $t=1$
$$ \color{red}{z \leq a^2 + 2a } $$

**DETAIL** $$\color{fuchsia}{ z(az-xy) = x+y }$$
and $$ z =  \frac{xy+t}{a}  $$
so that when $t=1,$ we get $az = xy+1$  or $az-xy = 1,$ so that $z(az-xy) = x+y$ tells us $z=x+y,$ when $t=1$

Comment: your answer looks suspicious in that it takes no consideration that $a$ is not a perfect cube.

Comment: whoever left a downvote, let us know why the answer is not correct so we can learn

Comment: @david, you will see in time. The two cases are $t < a^{2/3}$ and $t > a^{2/3}$

Comment: The final inequality $z<2a^2+2a-1$ is strictly weaker than the inequality $z<a^2+2a$ in the question.

Comment: @Servaes  fixed....

Comment: @Will Jagy, you stated in your proof that if  $a^{2/3} < t \le a-1 $ then $ty<a$, could you provide more details on how you arrived at this in your answer?

Comment: @DavidJones $  (tx-a) (a-ty) = t^3 -a^2 > 0 $  It is a little out of order

Comment: @Will Jagy , Probably am not picking everything from your proof because am an engineering student not a math major. I never understood the statement "The $t$ derivative of the right hand side is positive. At $t=a^{2/3} $ we would have rhs become $a^{1/3}$. The larger bound, valid over the entire t segment, is at $t=a−1$, when  $x≤a^2−3a+1$" . Also at the last stage of your proof for the last case, you said $z=x+y$ when $t=1$. How does this follow from your earlier result $z = (xy+t)/a$

Comment: @DavidJones  I just emailed you a numerical table, the address you used in October. Please compare that with the argument above. It will take me some time to remember enough to provide more detail than that. In any case, the mention of calculus is probably not entirely necessary, it just says that something increases as $t$ increases, thus giving an explicit bound on that quantity merely by evaluating at the two $t$ endpoints.

Comment: @DavidJones  alright, first item, we are simply evaluating $t^2 - \frac{a^2 - a}{t}$ and asking about its maximum over  that $t$ interval. Without calculus, it is still clear that this quantity increases as $t$ increases. Here $a^{2/3} < t \leq a-1.$  We plug $t=a-1$ into  $t^2 - \frac{a^2 - a}{t}$ to get $(a-1)^2 - \frac{a(a-1)}{a-1} = (a-1)^2 - a = a^2 - 3a + 1$

Comment: @DavidJones  near the top, the third formula says $az^2 -xyz - (x+y)=0$  so that   $z(az-xy) - (x+y)=0$ or $z(az-xy) = x+y \; . \;$  Next, when $t=1,$  the formula $z = \frac{xy+t}{a}$ says $az = xy+1,$ or $az-xy=1$  Finally, combine $z(az-xy) = x+y \; . \;$  and $az-xy=1,$  (when $t=1$)

Comment: Thank you, let me go through it again. I think I will get it this time round

Answer (score 1):

Below is $a=47,$  I told it to write small $t$ first. Concentrating on $t=1$ we can see how $x+y=z$

This does not hold at all for $t\geq 2,$  where we see immediately that $x>z$

---

```
==================================  

 a: 47  t: 1 w 8837   x 95   y 93 z 188
 a: 47  t: 1 w 9166   x 116  y 79 z 195
 a: 47  t: 1 w 9871   x 139  y 71 z 210
 a: 47  t: 1 w 10012  x 143  y 70 z 213
 a: 47  t: 1 w 11657  x 185  y 63 z 248
 a: 47  t: 1 w 13631  x 231  y 59 z 290
 a: 47  t: 1 w 17767  x 323  y 55 z 378
 a: 47  t: 1 w 21997  x 415  y 53 z 468
 a: 47  t: 1 w 30551  x 599  y 51 z 650
 a: 47  t: 1 w 39152  x 783  y 50 z 833
 a: 47  t: 1 w 56401  x 1151 y 49 z 1200
 a: 47  t: 1 w 108242 x 2255 y 48 z 2303

 a: 47  t: 2 w 2305   x 59   y 39 z 49
 a: 47  t: 2 w 26980  x 1124 y 24 z 574

 a: 47  t: 3 w 11894  x 743  y 16 z 253

 a: 47  t: 4 w 568    x 28   y 20 z 12
 a: 47  t: 4 w 803    x 53   y 15 z 17
 a: 47  t: 4 w 1555   x 119  y 13 z 33
 a: 47  t: 4 w 6584   x 548  y 12 z 140

 a: 47  t: 6 w 2732   x 340  y 8 z 58

 a: 47  t: 7 w 994    x 140  y 7 z 21

 a: 47  t: 8 w 1324   x 218  y 6 z 28

 a: 47  t: 10 w 104   x 14   y 6 z 2
 a: 47  t: 10 w 245   x 45   y 5 z 5

 a: 47  t: 12 w 59    x 7    y 5 z 1
 a: 47  t: 12 w 200   x 44   y 4 z 4

 a: 47  t: 14 w 61    x 11   y 3 z 1

 a: 47  t: 15 w 156   x 42   y 3 z 3

 a: 47  t: 17 w 64    x 15   y 2 z 1

 a: 47  t: 22 w 304   x 130  y 2 z 6

 a: 47  t: 23 w 916   x 435  y 2 z 19

 a: 47  t: 24 w 71    x 23   y 1 z 1

 a: 47  t: 45 w 1079  x 989  y 1 z 22

 a: 47  t: 46 w 2161  x 2069 y 1 z 45

================================== 

Sat Mar 20 21:24:04 PDT 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be a positive integer that is not a cube, and let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positive integers such that
$$(xz+1)(yz+1)=az^3+1.$$
Expanding the left hand side and rearranging a bit then shows that
$$az^2-xyz-(x+y)=0,\tag{1}$$
so $z$ is an integral root of a quadratic with discriminant $x^2y^2+4a(x+y)$. In particular this discriminant is a perfect square, so there exists a positive integer $v$ such that
$$x^2y^2+4a(x+y)=(xy+2v)^2,$$
and with a bit of rearranging we find the curious identity
$$(a-xv)(a-yv)=a^2-v^3.$$
We see that $v<a$ as otherwise the right hand side is negative, whereas the left hand side is not. Applying the quadratic formula to $(1)$ shows that
$$z=\frac{xy+\sqrt{x^2y^2+4a(x+y)}}{2a}=\frac{xy+(xy+2v)}{2a}=\frac{xy+v}{a},$$
where we have the $+$-sign because $z$ is positive. It follows that
$$z<\frac{xy}{a}+1,$$
so now to prove that $z<a^2+2a$ it suffices to show that $xy<a(a+1)^2$.

Comment: At the end, I think the last line is not quite right. It would suffice to show $xy<a(a^2+2a-1)$. The condition you have, $xy<a(a^2+2a+1)$ is a tiny bit weaker.  In any case, is this easy to establish? So far this has not used the fact that $a$ is not a perfect cube, so that maybe plays a role.

Comment: @alex.jordan I agree, and in fact the slighty weaker non-strict inequality
$$xy\leq a^3+2a^2-2a+1,$$
would even suffice, because $x$, $y$ and $a$ are integers. I have no idea anymore how to establish this.